# how to make html warp text as one cell in excel?

Tags: html, excel

I use html to make excel document , like this :

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]-->
    </head><body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="mso-number-format:\@;white-space:nowrap">test</td>
            <td style="mso-number-format:\@;white-space:nowrap">test<br/>hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but `<br/>` cause cross cell in excel.

[image: cross cell]

So how do i make the warp text in one cell ?

---

**Update :**

 I had found a method to solve it . Use style `mso-data-placement`:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    br{
        mso-data-placement:same-cell;
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a macro that's importing the data? If so, can you please post it, and any other methods you've tried?

Comment: I had found it , but there are so little info about excel html format .

Comment: "I had found it...", you found what? Some code? Please post it.

Comment: Solution . See my Updated question.

Comment: You should add your answer as solution instead of updating the question. If its solved your problem, accept the same so that the question will be marked as answered, this will save time for reviewers and will help other users to quickly find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a method to solve it . Use style mso-data-placement:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    br{
        mso-data-placement:same-cell;
    } 
</style>
```